# Use custome webserver to view xml file shows blank page in vs2013

Tags: xml, iis

Hi I have an xml file in my vs2013 project. If I set using the customer web server. It shows blank page during viewing in browser. If I change to use default setting and it works fine.  I already set the specific port for this webiste in IIS. Is my IIS setting or VS2013 cause the issue. Would someone tell me how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tell us which browser, please.

Comment: @komaflash, I don't think it is a browser issue because if I set it to 'use default web server' in property bag then it works.

Comment: Did you configured the website in IIS Control panel? What is your "default", the development server for debugging? More information needed. :)